Image not showing on live server ASP.NET MVC web application
This is my code which is on localhost as well on server but when I open on live server the image is not showing. But on localhost, the image is showing
<td class="text-center">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result["Picture"]?.ToString()))
    {
        string imagePath = Url.Content("~/Applicant_Photo/" + result["Picture"]);
        <img src="@imagePath" height="40" width="40" alt="Pic">
    }
    else
    {
        <span>No Picture</span>
    }
</td>


Have you check that images are being uploaded on the server?

Yes, sir, I have confirmed that the images are on the server. However, when I connect using the live connection string, only the data is displayed; the images are not showing
@asmak9

If you directly access the image through the browser (pasting and searching the generated URL), do you able to access & view the image?

No Sir@YongShun

@ZahabAbbas What error do you get? Is it a 404 not found? If it is an unauthorized access, then you need to give the appropriate permissions on the Applicant_Photo folder

It seems that you have uploaded images to the folder which do not have public access. Place your images to the public folder i.e. Content folder. Remember that the images you want to display on page require public access. Also try the production server URL within browser first to verify if image is able to access or not.
